# How we can create multiple forms on Magento product page?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

By default Magento provides facility of custom options in product page but we can create only one form for a product.

How we can create two or more **custom options forms** on product page?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using xml.
 Open local xml of your theme, and add it under the `<catalog_product_view>` reference as shown below.

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <reference name="product.info">
          <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.modelstats" as="modelstats" template="PATH TO TEMPLATE FOR THE TAB 1">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>TAB NO 1</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.contact" as="stelly.contact" template="PATH TO TEMPLATE FOR THE TAB 2">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>TAB NO 2</value></action>

            </block>

        </reference>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Clear Cache, then try.

Comment: Thanks @anz for try out. But this is not my consideration. I would like to know How can we create multiple "**'custom options'** form" associated with products. on the back end/ Admin section. I'll manage the frontend as required.

Comment: late to answer but just go to the admin section, open the product and at the bottom there must be a custom options tab, and you can add any number of options of multiple types.

Comment: Is it possible to add 'Field set' in that form??